# How to setup user preference for multiple users reading data from one table in a mysql database.?

Tags: database

I have put the contents of a book(5 MB in size) into a table in mySql / laravel. I built the frontend with blade/alpine js. Users can login and view the book contents on their browser.

It is my goal that when each user has logged in they can highlight and underline any text they want and save it. If they login on another device I want the highlighted and underlined text to still be there. When a new user logs onto the site they will have their own 'fresh' copy of the book that they can then highlight.

I am not sure how to do this, spent hours online trying to figure it out. I am thinking some kind of user preference needs to be setup but would not know how to do it. I am new to this. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

I looked at doing a new table for each user but it would use to much space as users increased in number.